# Spring Boot not registering ConversionService Converters at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

Spring Boot here. I have the following `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class AddressConfig {

    public void configureAddressConverters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new AddressConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new AddressDTOConverter());
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am simply trying to register some `Converter` impls to the Spring `ConversionService`:

```
public class AddressDTOConverter implements Converter<AddressDTO,AddressEntity> {

    @Override
    public AddressEntity convert(AddressDTO source) {

        AddressEntity addressEntity = new AddressEntity();
        // TODO: logic to convert the DTO to an entity goes here
        return addressEntity;

    }

}
```

When I set a breakpoint on one of the `registry.addConverter(...)` lines up in `AddressConfig` and start my server in debug mode, it doesn't look like it ever gets executed. And when I hit a REST endpoint that uses `ConversionService` to try and convert an `AddressDTO` into an `AddressEntity`, I get:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [myapp.AddressDTO] to type [myapp.AddressEntity]
```

So clearly Spring is not registering my converters at startup, and because of that, isn't able to use the `ConversionService` to do the converting for me. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your `AddressConfig` class that Spring can do anything with.  As its annotated with `@Configuration`, Spring will look there for bean definitions (methods annotated with `@Bean`), but you have none.  It doesn't extend any Spring configuration class that overrides a method to register the converter, so it's expected that the method in question is not getting invoked.

The simplest way to register those converters is just to annotate them with `@Component`, e.g.

```
@Component
public class AddressDTOConverter implements Converter<AddressDTO,AddressEntity> {

  @Override
  public AddressEntity convert(AddressDTO source) {
  }
}
```

The other option is to take your configuration class and have it implement `WebMvcConfigurer`, then implement the `addFormatters` method, such as this:

```
@Configuration
public class AddressConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {     
      registry.addConverter(new AddressConverter());
      registry.addConverter(new AddressDTOConverter());
  }
}
```

If you want to do this in a Configuration class, without marking your converters as `@Component`s, then you'll need to inject the `ConverterRegistry` and register the converters in a `@PostConstruct` method, as follows.

```
@Configuration
public class AddressConfig {

    private final ConverterRegistry converterRegistry;

    public AddressConfig(ConverterRegistry converterRegistry) {
        this.converterRegistry = converterRegistry;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerConverters() {
        converterRegistry.addConverter(new AddressConverter());
        converterRegistry.addConverter(new AddressDTOConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lane (+1) this is a REST API so I don't wanna muck with the `WebMvcConfigurer` if I can help it at all. I tried your suggestion to annotate the converters with `@Component` but that doesn't change anything. Are you sure I don't have to explicitly register the converters with the `ConversionService` somehow? Thanks again

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Yes, you must register them either explicitly or via registering them as components.  If you aren't seeing them registered, verify that you are importing the correct `Converter`.  Annotating your converters via @Component is the correct `spring-boot` way of registering them, see the third bullet point [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.auto-configuration).  By adding `@Component`, you are creating a `Converter` bean.

Comment: OK thats my disconnect @lane (+1 again), can you provide an example of how you would explicitly register them to `ConversionService#addConverter`? I'd prefer to do it from my `AddressConfig` class since its a configuration-related class by nature, but I can't seem to get Spring Boot to execute a method that I don't annotate as being a `@Bean`. Thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup see the additions to the answer, should guide you through using your existing configuration class with a couple slight modifications.  I highly recommend just marking your converters as `@Component` or construct them individually in a `@Configuration` class under methods marked `@Bean`